# Alternative to polling server to fetch data in Java client?

Tags: java, http, cakephp, asynchronous

My Java application needs to fetch data from server (running CakePHP on nginx). Is there an alternative way to fetch data without polling server? Currently I am making use of persistent HTTP connection and polling server every X seconds to see if any data is available.

Had it been a web browser, I could have used web sockets. What options do we have in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can implement some kind of Java Messaging System (JMS) like ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, WebsphereMQ, etc then you can listen for messages posted to your client. Of course your Java application still effectively polls for messages, but the performance would be much better than HTTP requests.

The Spring framework offers some excellent abstractions over a JMS implementation so you don't have to worry about the plumbing. You can either go with a simple [JmsTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html) or use [Spring Integration](http://java.dzone.com/articles/dont-use-jmstemplate-spring) as two options

Answer (score 0):

Does the data in your application change frequently? If so, polling might be the best - and easiest - way to get updates.

If not, you will have to build the web sockets feature yourself - have a "server" in your Java client that listens to a certain port. When you submit a request, have CakePHP log it, and have a cron job or the like that sends you data whenever it is updated.

This will be hard to get working if you are behind a firewall/NAT though. You can try it out, but I think polling the HTTP server will be easiest.

Answer (score 0):

The Telemetry feature of WebSphereMQ allows MQTT clients to connect to an MQTT channel. An MQTT app running on your server can publish the data as it changes, and the data will be pushed to remote JMS or MQTT clients which have subscribed to the appropriate topic. Polling is not involved.